# How to access the webservice in grails through secure layer

Tags: web-services, rest, grails, spring-security, jsonp

I have simple method in controller class.

```
Class TrainingController{

    def getTrainingsJson(){
          def trainingList  = Training.list()
          println "called===="
          //render trainingList as JSON
          render "${params.callback}(${trainingList as JSON})"
    }
}
```

Which gets the list of training, In my HTML page I have request as follows

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){

             $.getJSON('http://localhost:8080/training/getTrainingsJson?callback=?',            
              function(data) {
               console.log("success");
               alert(data);
             });

        });
    </script>
```

**The request is served only after the login. Without the login the response will be login page HTML format.**

**The request is across the servers (from php to grails). 
I want to ensure that secure communication must be established, So how to authenticate 
through json using spring security in grails.**

And How to ensure that Nobody can forge the request and get the response from the server.

And Do need to follow the REST Or Can i write the methods in existing controllers OR Do i need to create a separate controller/service for this kind of requests.

Answer (score 1):

If all access is through the browser, then spring authentication will take care of it - just secure the url accordingly. All requests (including ajax) will go through the spring auth

To prevent snooping consider implementing SSL

The Spring Security plugin [docs](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/) has more information on securing your application. In particular read about Authentication, IP Address restriction and Session Fixation Prevention